# Printing adds large white area to letter-size formatted HTML

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, printing

I am making a program that automatically formats a flyer. I have a `<div>` that is specified to be `width: 21.59cm; height: 27.94cm;` which is passed to a new window when I press a certain button to print the flyer out: (All elements that need to be printed fit perfectly inside this `<div>`)

I've ensured that the correct CSS stylesheet is passed to the new window, in addition to the following snippet:

```
printWindow.document.write("<style>
    @media print {
        html, body {
            width: 21.59cm; 
            height: 27.94cm;
        } 
        @page {
            size: Letter portrait;
        }
    }
</style>");

const printData = `<div style="width: 21.59cm; height: 27.94cm;">${printContent.innerHTML}</div>`;  // Put content in fixed size div
printWindow.document.write(printData);
```

I have verified that this is transferred correctly into the new window, and the formatting looks fine. However, in the print dialog preview, as well as any PDFs that are printed to, there is a giant blank white space at the bottom of the page.

Here is the formatted `<div>`, with the black border marking the 21.59cm x 27.94cm bounding box:
[image: format]

and here is the print dialog:
[image: print]

Any help is appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: A4 size is 210 x 297 mm

Comment: @Beller I am not using A4, I am using Letter size, which is 215.9 x 279.4mm

Comment: The font in the box with two para's looks different. You can see this because of the line breaks are not the same